# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statsmodels.api [ Python ]

Tags: python, pip, statsmodels

When I try pip install statsmodels.api command,
I had these errors

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statsmodels.api (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for statsmodels.api

Python version is Python 3.8.5

C:\Windows\system32>pip install statsmodels

Requirement already satisfied: statsmodels in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (0.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from statsmodels) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: patsy>=0.5 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from statsmodels) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.21 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from statsmodels) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from statsmodels) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from patsy>=0.5->statsmodels) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.21->statsmodels) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.21->statsmodels) (2020.1)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
pip install statsmodels
```

You're trying to install one submodule of a Python module/package.  You have to install the whole package.

If you've already done this, then you already have the `statsmodels.api` module and don't have to install anything else.

Comment: Then you already have the `statsmodels.api` module. - `import statsmodels.api` should work for you.

Comment: I tried these :

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

Comment: Your problem is something other than the `pip` command you're trying to run not working.  In fact, it's not complaining here about the `statsmodels.api` module, but rather the parent `statsmodels` module.  If you just run `import statsmodels`, does it work?  It works for me. So does `import statsmodels.api`.  All I've installed with `pip` is `statsmodels`.  Could you have two versions of Python that are getting mixed up, so you're installing the package into one version but running from the other?  It's unclear what your problem is, but it isn't that you need to get that `pip` command to work.

Comment: But I had these error: 

ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-708795ecaabf> in <module>
  2 import numpy as np
  3 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
--> 4 import statsmodels.api as sm
  5 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'

Comment: @Arosha if you done a `pip install` that has worked. that means you have different python environments. install statsmodels in the right environment.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you have configured your environments (if you have many). but ensure that you install your package in the correct environment. However, please try the following for me:

```
 conda install -c anaconda statsmodels
```